# 2d isometric map disappeared when reopening Unity project

Tags: unity, 2d, isometric

I closed my Unity project, came back the next day and opened it, but saw this :

[image: Pink grid]

Instead of this :

[image]

What should I do to recover the grid instead of having that pink area ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the pink tiles came from a Tile Palette which was not anymore in the project, erasing them with a tile from a Tile Palette which was still in the project solved that issue.

Comment: Did you delete that palette outside of Unity or while editing a different scene?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think it was outside of Unity.